# reload jqgrid from data sent to client over websockets

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, websocket

I am sending a string down from a websockets server to my client that has a jqgrid on it.

the string is a JSON object which I"m converting using eval() (I know that's not best practice, but this is just for a proof of concept at this point).

I'm just trying to reload the jqgrid with:

```
var obj = eval("(" + msg.data + ")");
$("#list").setGridParam({ "postData" : obj }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

where msg is the parameter in my socket.onmessage callback, if I alert (msg.data), I see my correctly formed JSON string, but my grid isn't reloading.

if I alert obj, I see that it's converting to an object correctly.

I also tried splitting out the trigger("reloadGrid") onto a separate line with my $("#list) prepending it...still not reloading.

any suggestions?

Comment: It seems I don't full understand what you do. First instead of `eval` you can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), but I don't understand why you need to convert JSON string `msg.data` to object and then use it as `postData: obj` instead of just using `postData: {myMsg: msg.data}`? In which format can you send the data to the server? Moreover it's difficult to give you and recommendation without having an example of the `msg.data`. Additionally it's unclear for me how you use websockets together with jqGrid.

Comment: Oleg. Thanks for the response.  I ended up just using datatype: jsonstring and datastr: msg.data to get it working.  As I said in my OP, this is just for a proof of concept so I was just trying to get the grid to reload data from data that was being pushed from a websocket server and I was able to do that using those two changes I mention in this comment.

Comment: I think that I understand now where you have the problem. I wrote the details in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `datatype: 'jsonstring'` and `datastr: msg.data` and you want reload the grid with another data you should understand that `datatype: 'jsonstring'` will be changed to `datatype: 'jsonstring'` after the first load. The `postData` parameter will be used only if you communicate with the server. In the case the `datatype` must be either `'json'` or `'xml'`. The `url` parameter should be set in the case too.

So I you can try to do the following:

```
$("#list").setGridParam({
    datatype: 'jsonstring', // reset the `datatype`
    datastr: msg.data       // set new value of the input data
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: sorta funny that you posted that answer which contained the exact thing I said I did in my comments.  But I do appreciate the effort so I'll check it off for you :P

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson: Probably I don't understand you correctly. It is very difficult if you post the question without more full code which explains *what you currently do*. I understood your comment about datatype: jsonstring and datastr: msg.data so that you used the way as your current way which follow to the problem which described in the question. You don't describe more how you integrated communication with websocket per JSON. If you can't use `jQuery.ajax` for communication, that the usage of `datetype: 'jsonstring'` could be helpful, but in any way I need *more details* to help you more